# How to read the content of an Axios post response?

Tags: javascript, typescript, axios

When I send the same `POST` request with a cURL command, I get this as response:

```
{"allowed":[],"error":null}
```

When I add the `POST` request in my code and print it with `console.log("response: ", response);` or `console.log("response: ", response.data);` , I get this printed

```
'response: ,[object Object]'
```

How can I see the content of the response printed in my logs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `console.log("response: ", JSON.stringify(response.data))` to see the content of the object in console.